# Alternative for 'Variable_name Cursor_name%rowtype '

Tags: postgresql

How to create record type variable in poatgresql.while I'm trying to create variable using the below
Variable_name   Cursor_name%rowtype it showing cursor is not existing

Comment: Perhaps it isn't?

Answer (score 0):

This construct isn't supported. Use `RECORD` type instead. PL/pgSQL supports %ROWTYPE only for tables (not for cursors).

```
DECLARE 
  r record;
  ...
BEGIN
  ...
  FOR r IN cursorvar
  LOOP
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Will try with record type